# cant groupby on certain column after merging 2 dataframes in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 data frames, `data` and `data_car_types`. 
After merging them:

```
data_all = pd.merge(data, data_car_types, on = 'vin', how = 'right')
```

I get a data frame with this info:

```
Data columns (total 21 columns):
vin                           11391 non-null object
time_stamp                    5700 non-null object
time_stamp1                   5700 non-null object
abs                           5700 non-null object
city                          5700 non-null object
accelerator_pedal_position    5700 non-null float64
brake_pedal_status            5700 non-null object
engine_temperature            5700 non-null float64
engineoil                     5700 non-null float64
fuel                          5700 non-null float64
headlamp_status               5700 non-null object
ignition_status               5700 non-null object
odometer                      5700 non-null float64
outside_temperature           5700 non-null float64
parking_brake_status          5700 non-null object
speed                         5700 non-null float64
tirepressure                  5700 non-null float64
transmission_gear_position    5700 non-null object
windshild_wiper_status        5700 non-null object
time_stamp2                   5700 non-null object
car_type                      11391 non-null obj
```

etc.

When I want to group by `car_type` it fails:

```
data_all.groupby('car_type')
```

I get:

> pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>   (pandas/index.c:3979)() pandas/index.pyx in
>   pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3843)()
>
> pandas/hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
>   (pandas/hashtable.c:12265)()
>
> pandas/hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
>   (pandas/hashtable.c:12216)()
>
> KeyError: 'car_type'

I don't understand what is wrong?

Comment: Edit your post with the output from `print(data_all.columns.tolist())` you may have a space in the column name

Comment: you were right, thank you, how i didn`t see it

Comment: It's a simple error, you won't see the hidden spaces in `df.info()` or when it displays the df so whenever you see `KeyError` it's good practice to do `print(data_all.columns.tolist())` as this will give you a list of the columns with quote marks to mark the beginning and end of the names so it becomes clear when there are spaces or non-printable characters

Comment: thank you very much